# Has comment notification become flaky in the last couple of days?

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

In the last couple of days, I seem to have lost a load of comment notifications. I'm used to the indicator being red virtually every time I log in - but I don't *think* I've seen it be red recently; there's been no indication of comments.

It's occasionally been light blue for the "general" notifications - it's *possible* that actually this has almost always been the case, and that reading those notifications has effectively wiped out the comment notifications.

Either way, it seems to be behaving differently recently, and definitely in a bad way for me. (Other users who are more interested in badges than comments, or who rarely get comments, may feel differently of course.)

Assuming there really has been a change, could someone in the know at least explain it so I know what to expect? (And ideally change it back, but...)

EDIT: The comments are still there, shown in the dropdown - but I need to check the dropdown to see if there *are* any new comments, and there's no indication which ones are new. (I need to keep going until I see the first one I recognize.)

EDIT: I normally use Chrome, but I've just tried it with Internet Explorer as well (and *no* SO windows open on Chrome). Still no red light :(

Comment: @Pekka: Yes. Will edit that into the question.

Comment: Okay, this is very bizarre. I can now see a notification of "Guess not. What about this?" - but I can't see that on the question itself. I also can't see Pekka's comment I originally replied to. Perhaps Pekka's deleted them?

Comment: The first comment was mine. Apparently the system tells you about deleted comments but not... comments that were once there.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Right. I've noticed that before - it's a bit disconcerting to start with, but not a big problem. Off to church now, so won't be up for more experiments for a couple of hours...

Comment: I deleted my comment after your edit, so that part is ok

Comment: As the red thing might be client side, what browser you have? Any chance you: 1) Switched browser 2) Upgraded to beta version (Chrome does it by itself sometimes) or 3) Installed some browser plugin/addon that might affect JavaScript?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I'm using Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m on Windows 7 - I believe I'm using the release channel. Note that I still get the notifications around badges/edits - just not comments.

Comment: So like you said, when you check the notifications the comment alerts also get reset as both reset upon clicking the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ - maybe it's worth trying to ask for feature request that will mark the inbox items as read only when actually clicking their tab.

Comment: I use the exact same browser version (albeit on OS X) and have not observed this problem - but then, I'm hardly active on SO these days so I get only very few comments in the first place. Hmm, weird.

Comment: @Pekka: Are you seeing comment notifications for Meta? I'm not even getting those. Will try on other machines and browsers and see if there's any difference.

Comment: @Jon yup, seems to work just fine on both sites.

Comment: I've been getting comment notifications as usual, maybe it's specific to SO?

Comment: Weirdly enough, I seemed to have the same issue last couple of days but I am not experiencing the same problem today. It could be the browser (Switched from Chromium to Firefox today) or could be the latest build.

Comment: Editing around browser-ness....

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe problems with Web sockets? Are you having same problems on train, or at work?

Comment: @Benjol: This is all at home. (I've been working from home for a few days, and will be until Wednesday.) I'd expect web socket problems to affect the badge notifications too.

Comment: Hmm. I've now tried on three computers - two failed, and one succeeded. I've just killed the cookies on this one, and that didn't help. Grr. (It's really frustrating...) EDIT: Eek! Just after posting this comment, it suddenly worked. Weird. Let's see whether it's now reliable...

Comment: And now it's sometimes there, sometimes not. Grr.

Comment: Hmm. Just noticed that I was never notified about comments on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141524/155160).

Comment: Does the error console say anything?

Comment: @Sklivvz: If you mean the Javascript console, no.